# Dataframe: copy one row into another while keeping different dtypes of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns of different datatypes (floats and ints). Two rows are in the wrong order and I need to swap them, but copying a row onto another does not work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        {"a":2.5, "b":10},
        {"a":2.7, "b":12},
        {"a":2.8, "b":16},
        {"a":3.1, "b":18}
    ])
```

This does copy the values, but afterwards all rows are of type 'float' (Series objects only have a single datatype.):

```
df.iloc[1] = df.iloc[2].copy()  # changes datatype if b to float
```

Copying the rows by using slices sets the whole row to NaN:

```
df.iloc[1:2] = df.iloc[2:3].copy()  # sets row 1 to NaN,NaN

a   b
0   2.5 10.0
1   NaN NaN
2   2.8 16.0
3   3.1 18.0
```

2 Questions:

- whats happening in the second case, where do the `NaN`s come from?
- how do I copy a row onto another row while keeping the datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whats happening in the second case, where do the NaNs come from?

Problem is different index values of sliced DataFrames, pandas cannot align rows, so NaNs are created:

```
print (df.iloc[1:2])
     a   b
1  2.7  12

print (df.iloc[2:3])
     a   b
2  2.8  16
```

> how do I copy a row onto another row while keeping the datatypes?

One solution is create one row DataFrame and change index name for alignment:

```
df.iloc[[1]] = df.iloc[[2]].rename(index={2:1}).copy()
```

More general if need indexing index values:

```
df.iloc[[1]] = df.iloc[[2]].rename(index={df.index[2]: df.index[1]}).copy()
print (df)

0  2.5  10
1  2.8  16
2  2.8  16
3  3.1  18
```

Converting to numpy array is posible, but then dtypes are changes.